# What is recommended lifetime of Database object in a web application?

Tags: .net, web, petapoco, object-lifetime

I consider using PetaPoco in a conventional web app. Saying conventional I mean

- handling requests in separate threads from a pool
- requests are quick: no long polling, streaming, etc
- but not necessarily ASP.NET, it may be for example Nancy

What should be the lifetime of the Database object, and that of the underlying DbConnection?

- globally static (I guess no, due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645682/))
- per-thread static, `[ThreadStatic]`
- per-request
- unit of work style: create and dispose as soon as the task is finished

I especially appreciate answers from those who run production apps with PetaPoco.

Comment: You *definitely* should avoid `ThreadStatic` with ASP.NET because of thread agility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request is the way to go

- globally static: you guess right. Will bring problems accessing the same recordset and others. Definitely no.
- per-thread static. You should avoid [ThreadStatic] in Asp.net
- per-request: works great
- unit of work style: It works great also (not my preference)

Comment: @Eduardo Does doing on per-request basis limit the effect of connection pooling?

Comment: @Matt In fact it fully uses the connection pooling to give new connections without performance penalties

Answer (score 1):

You need one object per thread, but you shouldn't associate the object with the thread itself, because handling a request can start in one thread and finish in another thread.

Using one object per request would normally be the best, at least for quick request handling. However that is not always simple. If you risk leaving objects without disposing them (for example if there is an exception), it's better to use one object for a limited task where you can make sure that it is disposed properly.

Comment: +1 for non-disposed objects risk. Can you elaborate more on "handling a request can start in one thread and finish in another thread". When is this possible?

Comment: @amartynov: This is called thread switching or thread agility (for further searching). Here is a blog post that I found giving a clear example: http://blog.idm.fr/2010/03/aspnet-thread-agility-or-why-threadstatic-should-not-be-used.html

Answer (score 1):

Database is a cheap object to create, so I just create it as needed. I use PetaPoco (or more specifically [AsyncPoco](https://github.com/tmenier/AsyncPoco) so I'm not tying up threads during I/O bound work) in a busy web app and this works great for me. [Others do prefer per-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653695/should-the-petapoco-database-class-be-created-once-per-request-or-every-time-it) though, and that should also work well.